# Where to save data entered by user until it is approved by admin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In my project, I want the signed-in user to insert data and wait for approval but the problem is where to save that unapproved data like if 400 signed-in users have inserted data then how can I manage that data until it is approved. Do I have to make it's another database table to save that unapproved data ?? or use the same database table ? if yes then how ?? Or did I can do this with javascript or jquery??. My database is in MySQL and using PHP. My form looks like this

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="FormVerification">
<input type="text" name="Input1" required value="<?php echo $Variable; ?>" placeholder="Enter Some Value">
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
//do something for varification 
}
?>
```

Any Suggestions ?? ?

Comment: In the same table, just add a `validated` flag to the row, so `validated=0` when user registers and the admin sets to `validated=1` when they have approved the user

Comment: @RiggsFolly validated flag datatype as a boolean ???? for this I have to change the whole queries which I write for searching don't you think that is complicated. You have to change the whole structure of queries ???

Comment: It could be a tinyint and 1,0. But yes, you should change up all your queries if that is what you want to accomplish. All you have to do is add to the where clause... validated = (1 or 0) depending on if you want validated entries or non validated

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion know I'm going to start working on it.. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only activation/approval you need then the easiest approach would be to insert a column in the actual table and call it "is_approved" or something similar.

Have that default to 0, and when an admin approves it set it to 1.

You can use that column to retrieve data not yet approved (where is_approved=0), and also to display the approved a data (is_approved=1).

Other than that you'd have the option of copying the table and name it something like pending_submission. Once the submission is approve you'd move the data to the approved table.

Comment: this is the easiest approach you can take to resolve this issue.

Comment: ok Thanks I'll start working on this idea and inform you if something gone wrong ::P